# I made some simple pygame code and it doesn't work

Tags: pygame, arrow-keys

I wrote a program using all pygame modules. Some of it looks like this:

```
#assigning keys to the key press library

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

#Key movements

if keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:

    c_one_y -= speed

if keys[pygame.K_s] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:

    c_one_y += speed

if keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:

    c_one_x -= speed

if keys[pygame.K_d] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:

    c_one_x += speed

screen.fill(maincolour)

pygame.draw.rect(screen, (225, 0, 0), (c_one_x, c_one_y, width, length))

pygame.display.update
```

The aim is to move a rectangle in any direction using wasd's and the arrow keys. My IDE isn't reporting any errors yet the rectangle isn't appearing where it is set to. I have tried various different approaches to the problem but none have worked. Got any suggestions?

Comment: Is your rectangle appearing *at all*  ... or just in the wrong pace?

Comment: OMG!... I'm so stupid.Thank you for pointing out my super obvious mistake. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't made `pygame.display.update()` a function. You have just written `pygame.display.update`.